# Selenium: Handling exceptions for element that may not be present

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a handful of pages where I want to look for an element, and if it is present, get the text. But I've run into a bit of a conundrum with respect to exception handling.

I can use WebDriverWait:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="className"]')))
```

But if this throws an exception, I technically have no way of knowing whether it occurred because the element is in fact not present on the page, or because of something else (e.g. I didn't wait long enough or there's some other error in the code).

In my particular case I've been able to deal with this so far by using the presence of some other elements on the page to infer whether the one I'm looking for will be present. However, I am bound to run into some pages where I can't use other elements as proxies.

Is there any way for me to distinguish between an exception caused by the element actually not being in the page source versus some other reason?

Comment: i use java and java throws 2 different types of exception - NoSuchElement and Timeout Exception

Comment: @lost Isn't a NoSuchElement exception and a Timeout exception while trying to locate an element the same thing, though?

Comment: NoSuchElement exception is thrown when we use driver.find and TimeOut Exception when we use explicit wait. Both implies the same thing - Element is not found in the DOM. But timeout exception does tell us that we waited for a particular amount of time.

Comment: I suggest you use **try-catch** block. So, in the try-block, you can have the code for waiting for the element and getting the text. In case, any error/exception occurs, then catch is there to handle it.

Comment: Actually TimeOutException will also be caused due to NoSuchElementException if you go for explicit wait.

Comment: Maybe there is no good solution to my problem, but I'm struggling to understand how any of the above would help me distinguish between the element actually not being present and the driver failing to find it for some other reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the Exception you want to catch and then do something in the catchblock, refer to the Java Doc here to give you more insight on exceptions

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html

```
   public void aMethod() {
       try {
        //do someting
               } catch( Exception e ) {
        textLog( "Element not present -------" );
       detailedText( e );
    }

}
```